# C++ pointer output memory address from 0 to 242 and stops

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

My objective in the below code was to see that the memory address is actually changing due to p++ (which it does) but what I can't figure it out is why the program stops (but not terminated) to show memory address past i=242? In other words, past 242 lines the program does nothing and the last line "that's it" is never executed.

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout<<"start..."<<endl;
int x=100;
int *p = &x;

for (int i=0; i<300; i++)
{
    cout<<i<<". &p:="<<p<<" v:="<<*p<<endl;
    p++;
}

cout << "that's it!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

the result:

```
start...
0. &p:=0x7fff59c30c34 v:=100
1. &p:=0x7fff59c30c38 v:=1706885214
2. &p:=0x7fff59c30c3c v:=32767
3. &p:=0x7fff59c30c40 v:=1505954904
```

.
. 
.

```
240. &p:=0x7fff59c30ff4 v:=946024503
241. &p:=0x7fff59c30ff8 v:=892744247
242. &p:=0x7fff59c30ffc v:=13617
```

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior, because it is dereferencing an invalid pointer

Comment: It goes well on my computer.

Comment: it is undefined, might goes well 100 years and then stop to goes well

Comment: Try run the program directly instead of inside a cmd. It's mostly like they may share the memory thus causing the program to pause.

Comment: I got the freeze when running it in a cmd console but OK when running it directly.(even if I loop 3000 times)

Comment: @Immueggpain at what point did it stop for you? i=?

Comment: @adhg 244      . Did you try run it directly?

Comment: obviously this is non deterministic - probably the OS decides when ?! thanks @Immueggpain

Comment: @adhg Of course it's OS dependent. You are using shells from the OS!

Comment: Hey, can I post an answer and you may upvote it? I really want some rep...

Comment: @Immueggpain you're funny. Do it

Comment: @adhg I have posted my answer. Check it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x=100;
int *p = &x; //you allocated one int and you can point to it

for (int i=0; i<300; i++)
{
    cout<<i<<". &p:="<<p<<" v:="<<*p<<endl;
    p++;
//  ^^^
//  here you are pointing your pointer at next 4 bytes, but 
//  dereferencing it is an undefined behavior that you actually do observe
//  you don't know what is next address pointing to and you are not allowed
//  to dereference it
}
```

as I said in comments this is **undefined**, might goes well 100 years and then stop to go well.

solution for your test might be:

```
int *p = new int[300]; //now you can point to any address within this table

for (int i=0; i<300; i++)
{
    cout<<i<<". &p:="<<p<<" v:="<<*p<<endl;
    p++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using p++, you are trying to access some memory not assigned/allocated to your program. I guess 242 is just some arbitrary number your OS stops your attempt. It is not quite right and will not be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behavior on multiple accounts.

```
int x=100; int *p = &x;
```

so far so good. That allows you to do *p (getting 100) and ++p, setting the pointer to one-past x.

Dereferencing that pointer is not allowed. Incrementing it further is not allowed either. Pointer math is legal within bounds of array from [0] to the one-past-end, counting solo objects as [1] array.

The bottom line is after the first iteration anything can happen.

Comment: mmmm...actually, this code is nonsense in the notion of 'dereferencing' (why would anyone do that), but out of curiosity, why 242 (if it was 255 - I may have convinced myself why) (thanks anyway)

Comment: possibly your platform uses a descending stack and at that address you pass the top. Page fault downward would just extend the stack but in the other direction you walked off the map

Answer (score 1):

OS maps memory pages to process of say size 1k , 4k 8k etc
The pointer p is pointing to the address which is in mapped 'pages', Once the address which pointer p points to goes beyond the mapped pages, The kernel knows that you are refrencing invalid memory  and hence raises signal.

Answer (score 1):

When running the program directly instead of inside a cmd. Everything is OK.(even if I loop 3000 times)

Then I got the freeze when running it in a cmd console.

So I guess that it's mostly like the program and the cmd shell may share the memory thus causing the freeze.

So it's really OS dependent.